# Upload file to Cloudinary Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, cloudinary

I am using the following html to allow the user to upload images:

```
<input class="upload" type="file" id="upload">
```

I have the following method to upload to Cloudinary:

```
      cloud : function (source) {
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(source, function(result) { console.log(result) }, 
      { public_id: "test" });

  },
```

And the following to detect input and call the method:

```
'change #upload': function(event, template) {
          var imgVal = document.getElementById("upload");
          Meteor.call("cloud",imgVal);
      },
```

I receive this error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'cloud' TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'match'
I20150813-10:10:38.007(-4)?     at C:\Users\Raj\art\.meteor\local\isopacks\npm-container\npm\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:61:34
I20150813-10:10:38.007(-4)?     at call_api (C:\Users\Raj\art\.meteor\local\isopacks\npm-container\npm\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:368:22)
I20150813-10:10:38.008(-4)?     at Object.exports.upload (C:\Users\Raj\art\.meteor\local\isopacks\npm-container\npm\node_modules\cloudinary\lib\uploader.js:58:12)
I20150813-10:10:38.008(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.cloud (app\art.js:132:28)
I20150813-10:10:38.008(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150813-10:10:38.008(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150813-10:10:38.008(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150813-10:10:38.008(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
I20150813-10:10:38.009(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150813-10:10:38.009(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
=> Meteor server restarted
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I have the following packages.json file: `{
  "cloudinary": "1.2.2"

}`

Answer (score 0):

Image Upload dont support the Meteor.call function.

Try:

```
'yourcollection'.allow({ <-- without the ''.
  insert: function() {return true},
  update: function() {return true},
});
```

put it in your lib/yourcollection.js

Comment: After doing this,  I received this error: `W20150813-10:32:19.667(-4)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/projects/insert' is already defined`

Comment: btw which packages do you installed ??
may you could list it above ?

Comment: go in your meteor app folder

then go into .meteor and then packages then copy paste the packages here

Comment: I used the meteor-hacks npm to install cloudinary, perhaps this is why I received `error: unknown package in top-level dependencies: cloudinary`

Comment: mhh thats tricky now maybe you should install the normal meteor-platform

Answer (score 0):

`cloudinary.uploader.upload` expects the first argument `file` to be a string. You are sending an `HTMLInputElement`.

You can extract the selected file(s) as a base64 encoded string from the input element using the `files` property and `FileReader`:

```
'change #upload': function(event, template) {
    var imgVal = document.getElementById("upload");
    var files = imgVal.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and upload each image file.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          Meteor.call("cloud",e.target.result);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  },
```

*(Source adapted from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.)*

Please note that cloudinary_npm was designed for server side operation - however I believe the above code would work.